# invariant violation, invalid hook call, useApolloClient

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm getting this error in React Native:

"Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hoks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. etc"

My code (simplified) is this:

```
import { useApolloClient } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
// code

const handleRedirectCalculator = React.useCallback(() => {
    const client = useApolloClient();
    client.clearStore();
    navigation.push('CurrencyConverter');
}, []);

return (
<View>
  <MessageErrorButton
      message='El tiempo de tu cotización a caducado'
      onPress={() => handleRedirectCalculator()}
  />
```

What I want is to get use the useApollo hook to get the client then use the clearStore on the client. How can I fix my code?

Comment: I think you can define `const client = useApolloClient();` outside the **useCallback**

Answer (score 1):

Thats because as stated in React [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) you can't have hooks inside nested functions, useApollo is a hook itself, so you have to take it out and approach your problem differently

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fix by removing the call o the hook outside:

```
import { useApolloClient } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
// code

const client = useApolloClient();

const handleRedirectCalculator = React.useCallback(() => {
    client.clearStore();
    navigation.push('CurrencyConverter');
}, []);

return (
<View>
  <MessageErrorButton
      message='El tiempo de tu cotización a caducado'
      onPress={() => handleRedirectCalculator()}
  />
```